# Importar a una carpeta desde otra carpeta en Python

Tags: python

Tengo una carpeta principal *(Proyecto0)* y dentro de ella las carpetas (Models, Views (=GUI), Controllers (=¿realmente quiere...? y alguna más, que contienen  los distintos archivos. Estos archivos llaman a archivos que están en otras carpetas, por ejemplo, estando en la carpeta *Controllers*, archivo *CreateProductController* y quiero importar de la carpeta *Models* el archivo *Product* mediante:

```
from Models.Product import product (por ejemplo).
```

En las importaciones tengo

```
import sys

import os

myDir = os.getcwd() # =Current Working Directory)

sys.path.append(myDir)
```

El path es *C:\Users\Pepito\Documents\Producto0...*
Aclaro que en todas las subcarpetas he colocado un archivo vacío

**init**.py

Recibo el error:

> Import "Models.Product" could not be resolved.

Y es cierto que no está en el directorio "peticionario" Controllers. ¿Cómo debo hacerlo para que se obtengan archivos de otros directorios? Muchas gracias.

Comment: podrías compratir la estructura de tu proyecto?

Answer (score 0):

hace un tiempo me topo con el mismo problema, investigando di con un snippet que me conecta las carpetas como lo estas pidiendo, si uno quiere tener el codigo mas ordenado.Te comparto la estructura de ejemplo en una app MVC.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En las Cuales estan las siguientes clases y sus métodos.

Carpeta Models - **FruitModel**

```
class FruitModel:
def __init__(self) -> None:
    super(FruitModel, self).__init__()

def GetAllItems(self):
    myFruits = ['Uva', 'Fresa', 'Melón', 'Manzana', 'Piña','Arándano']
    return myFruits
```

Carpeta Controllers- **FruitController**

```
import os 
import sys

PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(
               os.path.dirname(__file__), 
               os.pardir))
sys.path.append(PROJECT_ROOT)

from Models.FruitModel import FruitModel


class FruitController:
def __init__(self) -> None:
    super(FruitController, self).__init__()
    # Create object of Operatios
    self.ObjectOperatios = FruitModel()

def SortFruits(self):
    result = self.ObjectOperatios.GetAllItems()
    result.sort()
    return result
```

Las siguientes lineas de codigo son las importantes ya que nos permites salir del directorio un un nivel arriba y seleccionar una carpeta que necesitamos.

```
PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(
               os.path.dirname(__file__), 
               os.pardir))
sys.path.append(PROJECT_ROOT)
```

Carpeta Views- **app**

```
import os 
import sys

PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(
               os.path.dirname(__file__), 
               os.pardir))
sys.path.append(PROJECT_ROOT)

from Controllers.FruitController import FruitController

class ViewApp:
def __init__(self) -> None:
    super(ViewApp, self).__init__()
    # Create Object 
    self.ObjectController = FruitController()


def ShowElements(self):
    result = self.ObjectController.SortFruits()

    for item in result:
        print(item)

if __name__ == '__main__':
ObjectMainApp = ViewApp()
ObjectMainApp.ShowElements()
```

Cabe destacar que todas las carpetas tienen el archivo **init**.py para poder utilizar los módulos.

Comment: José Escarcega. Gracias por tu respuesta, pero no consigo hacer que me funcione. Pregunto: ¿estarías dispuesto a solucvonarme este problema de enlace enre los dos archivos? ¿Cuánto me cobrarías? Espero tus noticias